# iPhoneSDK: Launching multiple views from within a single view?

Tags: iphone

I have a very simple entry form. After a button is pressed, I need to show two additional views launched from that view. Here is the error. I am not understanding the error. I thought I had declared two different types. Comments appreciated.

009-11-03 17:17:29.008 eProcessing-iPhone[34257:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported ()'

Here is the code:

```
confirmViewController *anotherViewController = [[confirmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"confirmView" bundle:nil];

//set properties
anotherViewController.strConfirmation = [request responseString];
anotherViewController.strCardNumber = txtCardNumber.text;
anotherViewController.strExpires = txtExpires.text;
anotherViewController.strAmount = txtGrandTotal.text;   

[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];


//reset interface
if([anotherViewController.strApproval compare:@"""Y"] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    txtCardNumber.text = @"";
    txtExpires.text = @"";
    txtGrandTotal.text = @"";
    txtZip.text = @"";
    txtCCV2.text = @"";
    txtEmail.text = @"";
    txtInvoice.text = @"";
}

[anotherViewController release];


//show signature
sigCaptureViewController *yetAnotherViewController = [[sigCaptureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sigCaptureView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
[yetAnotherViewController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps where you say

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

you mean

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yetAnotherViewController animated:YES];
```

The error is saying you can't have the same view controller on the navigation view stack twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same view controller twice:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

The error is stemming from the fact that you're doing:

```
[anotherViewController release];
```

And then a few lines later you're doing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```